# Python 3: Using exec(open("path").read()) to open File and run code from file

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing at the Moment a little Game to learn a bit Python 3 and I want to import another Game by using exec() to get a File and execute the Script:

While running this script:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24581759/

I want to use this script as a game inside a game:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24581775/

The Part where it gets the File and runs the Script:

```
class Kitchen(Thing):

    def enter(self):
        print(dedent("""
            you in kitchen.
            """))

        action = input("> ")

        if action == "use pc":
            exec(open("//home/opusa/probes/ex35.py").read())
            return 'kitchen'

        if action == "make sandwitch":
            print(dedent("""
                you made sandwitch. now way better.
                """))
            return 'the_end'

        else:
            print(dedent("make sandwitch"))
            return 'kitchen'
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mygame.py", line 115, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "mygame.py", line 29, in play
    next_thing_name = current_thing.enter()
  File "mygame.py", line 75, in enter
    exec(open("//home/opusa/probes/ex35.py").read())
  File "<string>", line 77, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 70, in start
NameError: name 'bear_room' is not defined
```

If I use other Scripts everything works fine...

Please point out my Mistake and where I can read up on this. Couldn't find anything helpful so far.
Thanks!

Comment: Links you provided are dead. Please write codes directly to the post instead of showing them via images.

Comment: @Shibli they are not dead, just bad formatted...

Comment: Thanks. Please consider the second suggestion as well. If the codes are too long consider narrowing down the problem.

Comment: you can instead import one scrip into the other

Comment: I can open the links just fine, but ok. The upper Snipet is the Part where I try to call it and then I get the 'not defined' Message. But the Code I try to call from the File on itself works fine. Import? I'll try it.

Comment: Did you solve it?